# Could not parse date: No date part found. Input was:"Tue, 3 Jun 2014 1:12:28 -0400"

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Pop3Client to GetMessage from my mail box, like below code

```
OpenPop.Mime.Message msg = objClient.GetMessage(i);
```

It works fine but giving error for some mails 
error message is

```
Could not parse date: No date part found. Input 
was:"Tue, 3 Jun 2014 1:12:28 -0400"
```

I checked the mail and date in mail box and it looks same to mail which working properly. I also do nothing with date in `GetMessage` method, Can anybody know why this error occur and how to solve that

**Edit** 
I also found that the mail having issue had date time format like `Sun, 18 May 2014 0:59:56 -0400` and the mail working properly having date time format like `27 May 14 16:28:00 UT`

Comment: Where is this happening? Are you sure `GetMessage` do some _parsing_ stuff?

Comment: objClient is a object of Pop3Client class and i do not change any thing in GetMessage method. I think it do parsing stuff thats why i am getting the error

Comment: I use the `GetMessageAsBytes` instead of `GetMessage` and it is giving me the byte data and also i convert it to string. I am working on it to solve the problem